# How to find POS Printer installed in Network using POS for .Net

Tags: .net

I am working with one POS system and got stuck at one place. The problem I have is with POS printer in Network. Let me describe you my problem in detail.

I have one POS Printer attached to my network. Printer is having direct LAN cable connection. It is not installed on any computer. I have successfully connected that printer through my windows 7 operating system.

Now my problem is how can I access that network printer using Microsoft POS sdk. I have already tried GetDevices method of POS library. it returns me null.

Do anyone have any experience with the same.

Thanks in advance.